# DevExpress PivotSummaryDisplayType.AbsoluteVariation Custom Calculation

Tags: c#, devexpress

Is there a way to handle the PivotSummaryDisplayType.AbsoluteVariation calculations with a custom method for PivotTables?

My issue is occurring because I have two fields which contain a custom object, and the AbsoluteVariation field is not properly interacting with these objects. I want to catch the call for an AbsoluteVariation calculation on those fields and do it myself. I have been unable to find any information on this and was hoping Stack Overflow would have my answer.

I would also be open to a custom display type handling like PivotSummaryType.Custom but was unable to find anything.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You will have a better luck asking this question on DevExpress support. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ or try this https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=PivotSummaryDisplayType.AbsoluteVariation+Custom+Calculation+site%3A+www.devexpress.com